# Command redirection operators in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to get to know how to redirect output of some program in PowerShell to file.
In cmd I used to do it like this:

```
some.exe > test.in
```

In PowerShell like this:

```
.\some.exe > test.in
```

But this code doesn't work:

```
for($i = 0; $i -le 5; $i++)
{
  & '.\some.exe > test.in'
}
```

So, could you tell me, what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that works

```
for($i = 0; $i -le 5; $i++)
{
    nslookup.exe www.google.com | findstr "Addresses:" >> test.in
}
```